# 祖先ディレクトリにあるファイル (Mintfile) を見つけてパスを取得したい

Tags: unix, zsh, shell

カレントディレクトリやその親ディレクトリ、さらなる祖先ディレクトリの直下にある、特定のファイル名のファイルを指定する方法を教えていただけますと嬉しいです。

ただし、そのようなものが複数ある場合、最も近い祖先のディレクトリの直下にあるファイルを示したいのです。

例えば、以下のようなフォルダ構造で、カレントディレクトリが `foo/src/hoge` だとします。

```
$ ls -R foo
Mintfile  src/

foo/src:
hoge/  Mintfile

foo/src/hoge:
fuga.swift
$ cd foo/src/hoge
```

この場合、 `foo/src/Mintfile` のみを指し示したいのです。

関数を定義して呼び出すことで、動いてはいるのですが、もっと良い表現がある気がしています。
zshのワイルドカードや`find`コマンドを用いた、できるだけシンプルな表現を知りたいと思っています。

ちなみに、定義した関数は以下のようなものです:

```bash
function mintfile_path {
    ( # execute inside subshell to restore working directories
        while : # infinite loop
        do
            local dir=$(pwd)
            local file_path="$dir/Mintfile"
            
            if [[ -f $file_path ]]
            then
                echo $file_path
                break
            fi
            
            if [[ $dir == "/" ]]
            then
                break
            fi
            
            cd ..
        done
    )
}
```

2023-04-22 土曜日 追記:

本当はcdしたりサブシェルを使ったりしたくないので、dirnameを使って書き直してみました。

```bash
function mintfile_path() {
    local dir=$(pwd)
    while : # infinite loop
    do
        local file_path="$dir/Mintfile"

        if [[ -f $file_path ]]
        then
            echo $file_path
            return
        fi

        if [[ $dir == "/" ]]
        then
            break
        fi

        dir=$(dirname $dir)
    done
}
```

Comment: cdを使ってしまうと、カレントディレクトリが移動してしまいます。それが望む動作であればいいのですが、そうしたくない場合はdirnameコマンドを使うと、パスからディレクトリ部分を抽出することが出来ます。

Comment: @dameo カレントディレクトリの移動は望まない副作用でした。dirnameはファイルのファイルパスのディレクトリ部分を得るのに使うものだと思い込んでいて、ディレクトリのパスに対して適用すると親ディレクトリのパスが得られるということを今回知りました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 理想的にはzshのglobの一種として .../Mintfile 等と書けたら理想なんですが、そういうglobは探した限りは見つけられませんでした。

Answer (score 3):

> 本当はcdしたりサブシェルを使ったりしたくない

```bash
function mintfile_path {
  local dir="$PWD"; [ "$dir" = '/' ] && dir=''
  while :
  do
    [ -f "${dir}/Mintfile" ] && { echo "${dir}/Mintfile"; return; }
    [ -z "$dir" ] && return;
    dir="${dir%/*}"
  done
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。 直前のディレクトリを保存しておくという発想はありませんでした。

Comment: アプデありがとうございます! かなり短く書けるのですね